# Retrieving variables from table function

Tags: r, aggregate, grouping

I want to calculate the number of active V2 for a particular V1. I am using `table()` function, but here I am not knowing how to split the `output(a0[2])`. `class(a0[2])` is a data.frame

```
> a
   V1     V2
1   1 lapsed
2   1 lapsed
3   1 active
4  33 active
5  33 active
6  55 lapsed
7  55 lapsed
8  55 active
9  55 active
10 55 active
> a0 <- aggregate(a$V2 ~ a$V1, data= a, function(x){table(x)})
> a0
  a$V1 a$V2.active a$V2.lapsed
1    1           1           2
2   33           2           0
3   55           3           2
> a0[1]
  a$V1
1    1
2   33
3   55
> a0[2]
  a$V2.active a$V2.lapsed
1           1           2
2           2           0
3           3           2
```

I am trying to calculate for a unique value in `a$V1`, the number of (active)/(active + lapsed). Want the output to look like below :

```
col1    active/(active+lapsed)
1            1/3
33           2/2
55           3/5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a1 <- data.frame( col1 = a0[[1]], col2 = a0[[2]][1:3], col3 = a0[[2]][4:6] )
a1$col4 <- with( a1, paste( col2, "/", ( col2 + col3 ), sep = "" ) )
a1$col5 <- with( a1, col2 / ( col2 + col3 ) )
> a1
  col1 col2 col3 col4      col5
1    1    1    2  1/3 0.3333333
2   33    2    0  2/2 1.0000000
3   55    3    2  3/5 0.6000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `aggregate`:

```
DF <- read.table(text="   V1     V2
1   1 lapsed
2   1 lapsed
3   1 active
4  33 active
5  33 active
6  55 lapsed
7  55 lapsed
8  55 active
9  55 active
10 55 active")

tmp <- table(DF)
res <- cbind.data.frame(rownames(tmp), 
                        paste(tmp[,"active"], 
                              rowSums(tmp), 
                              sep="/"))
names(res) <- c("col1", "active/(active+lapsed)")

#  col1 active/(active+lapsed)
#1    1                    1/3
#2   33                    2/2
#3   55                    3/5
```